# Remove payment option when a specific shipping method is selected

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods, shipping-methods

How can I remove a specific payment option when a specific shipping method is checked?

Below is a screenshot explanation:

[image: Screenshot explanation]

Answer (score 5):

There is a function on the payment abstract that checks if a method can be used based on the quote. `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isApplicableToQuote` if this only is applicable to the pay on delivery method then simply rewrite the payment method `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery` and add your own `isApplicableToQuote`. Here you can check on the quote object what shipping method has been selected and return if the payment method can be used.

```
public function isApplicableToQuote($quote, $checksBitMask)
{
    if (Check if shipping method is X) {
        return false;
    }
    return parent::isApplicableToQuote($quote, $checksBitMask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't want to create a new payment_method you can use de event **payment_method_is_active** thrown in Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable.
In the Observer you will see that the event is fired once for every payment_method of your Magento and if you want to disable one of them you should do this in your Observer class

```
public function disallowPaymentMethod($observer) {
    if ($observer['method_instance']->getCode() == 'desired_payment_method_code') {
        $observer['result']['isAvailable'] = null;
    }
}
```

And that's it!